# Mouseover event triggered by Child Elements - how to stop this?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, prototypejs, dom-events, scriptaculous

I have this interface I want to build using Effect.Move from scriptaculous (with Prototype, of course).

When the top `div` is triggered on a mouseover, a `span` tag is to move 50 pixels to the left - and reset without movement to the original location on mouseout. The problem is, any time this `div` element is entered from a child element, the element I want moved moves an additional 50 pixels. I've tried using `relatedTarget` and `toElement` to stop this event from propogating, but to no avail. Here is the code, as of yet incomplete:

```
e.observe('mouseover', function(evt) {
   var block = e.down('span');

   if(evt.target == block && !evt.relatedTarget.descendantOf(block)){
    new Effect.Move(block, { x: -50, duration: 0.4, 

    });
   } else {

   }

  });
```

HTML Sample:

```
<div class='trigger'>
  <span class='to-be-moved'>...</span>
  <p>Child Element</p>
  <h2>Another Child Element</h2>
  <a>Link</a>
</div>
```

I'm totally lost here - any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use ["mouseenter" and "mouseleave"](http://demos.mootools.net/Mouseenter) instead of "mouseover" and "mouseout"? They will only trigger once even with child elements, and Prototype [supports it since 1.6.1](https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/commit/9d7a981e4c434ee7ca5a1219ab5a150552c411d1).

Comment: Sadly only helpful for certain cases, not for stuff like updating a position continuously.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
function hover(elem, over, out){
    $(elem).observe("mouseover", function(evt){
        if(typeof over == "function"){
            if(elem.innerHTML){
                if(elem.descendants().include(evt.relatedTarget)){ return true; }
            }
            over(elem, evt);
        }else if(typeof over == "string"){
            $(elem).addClassName(over);
        }
    });
    $(elem).observe("mouseout", function(evt){
        if (typeof out == "function") {
            if(elem.innerHTML){
                if(elem.descendants().include(evt.relatedTarget)){ return true; }
            }
            out(elem, evt);
        }else if(typeof over == "string"){
            $(elem).removeClassName(over);
        }
    });
    return elem;
}
```

Usage is:

```
hover($('el_id'), function(elem, evt){
    /* Mouse over code here */
},
function(elem, evt){
    /* Mouse out code is here */
});
```

It's very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298329/how-to-get-the-src-of-a-clicked-image-with-prototype/4316871#4316871).

If you're looking for a specific element that triggered the `onmouseover` event, use Prototype's `Event.findElement(...)` method in order to sift through unwanted children.

Serkan's answer is a hoky way of completing the task but won't work in all browsers.