# Prototype JS: mouseover with timer?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, prototypejs, mouseover, dom-events

I'm new to Prototype JS (and javascript in general), and I'm trying to make an overlay appear after the user has hovered over an element on the page for half a second. Currently, I'm accomplishing this with:

```
$$("a.tag").invoke('observe', 'mouseover', function() {
//my code here
});
```

This code makes the overlay appear when the trigger element is moused over, but how do I add the half second pause?

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
var timerId;

$$("a.tag").invoke('observe', 'mouseover', function() {
  timerId = setTimeout(function() {
     // code here
  }, 500);
});

$$("a.tag").invoke('observe', 'mouseout', function() {
  if (timerId) {
    cancelTimeout(timerId)
    timerId = null;
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the answer. I wanted to do something slightly different...instead of adding a half second pause, I wanted to trigger the function if the mouse has been over the element for more than 0.5 seconds. With the code above, an overlay will still appear if I hover over an element for let's say 0.1 seconds, it will just be delayed. Any idea about how to check the length of time that the mouse has been over the element?

Comment: Sorry silly me, I understand now. I'll work something out and edit my post :)

Comment: If your <a> tag ever should have something other in them besides text-only, you will need to use "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" instead - mouseover is triggered too often otherwise. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095546/mouseover-event-triggered-by-child-elements-how-to-stop-this/4118644#4118644

Answer (score 2):

I Think you could add a class `waitingEndDelay` to your element. 
Then code your "show function" in order to be executed only if element has no `waitingEndDelay` class. At the end of the delay remove `waitingEndDelay`.

Comment: The show function is not called after the delay times out, so this would not work.