# How to get the src of a clicked image with prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, invoke

I am struggling to get the image src of a image when its clicked. I just need the `jQuery(this).attr("src")` but in prototype, `this.readAttribute` doesn't work. I get: “this.readAttribute is not a function”

```
$$('.more-views > ul > li > img').invoke('observe', 'click',  this.updateImage.bind(this));

updateImage: function (){
 //var src = jQuery(this).attr("src").replace("thumbnail/66x66", "image");//changes src from thumbnail to large image
 Needs the above but in prototype.

 //jQuery('#image').attr("src", src);//updates large image
 this.imageEl.writeAttribute("src","http://www.timelapseme.com/images/logonew.png");

 val_scale = !this.showFull ? this.slider.value : 1;
       this.scale(val_scale);

},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
updateImage: function (){

var src = $(this).readAttribute('src');

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks wajiw I fixed it by var that = this, so I could use it later and getting rid of .bind(this)

Answer (score 0):

You're binding an event, so the click-handler should be:

```
...
updateImage: function(event)
   {
      var img = Event.findElement(event, 'IMG');
      var src = img.src;
   }
...
```